# Different values for the coefficients of binomial logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I have built a binomial logistic model and I am trying to print the coefficients of the equation.I used the summary(step.model) and then ran exp(cbind(coef(step.model), confint(step.model))) and i got different values for the coefficients. Does anyone know why and which values should i trust? Thank you

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -4.66465    0.81457  -5.727 1.03e-08 ***
var1         1.16920    0.54048   2.163   0.0305 *  
var2        -0.05930    0.03710  -1.599   0.1099    
var3         0.01961    0.01008   1.946   0.0517 .
```

```
exp(cbind(coef(step.model), confint(step.model)))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                              2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.009422584 0.001827827 0.04561167
var1        3.219411450 1.137717550 9.59813450
var2        0.942421860 0.872727880 1.01007336
var3        1.019807057 0.998665589 1.03935784
```

Comment: What is step.model?

Comment: Why did you take the exponent of the coefficients?

Comment: @frank is just the name of my model ```step.model <- glm(decision ~., data = train.data,family = "binomial")```

Comment: @Dave2e i just used a line of code I found for the coef. So you suggest that the exponent is wrong and I should the values for the coefficients that the summary function returns?

Comment: Yes, $e^{-4.66} = 0.009422$.  The coefficients from the summary statement are the coefficients for the fitted model, I don't see the need to manipulate the values unless you are trying to express them in a different form.  And to save a later headache be sure to use the  `predict()` function for the validate test set.

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384075/r-calculate-and-interpret-odds-ratio-in-logistic-regression)